# How can I save an image to my app?

Tags: java, android, saving-data

I am making an app that will let users take photos and save them to the app, which will be password protected.  So far, the app can take a picture, retrieve it, and set it to an image view.  However, when I restart the app the image goes away.  How can I save it?

```
int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
Uri imageUri;

public void takePic(View view){


    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "filename_" +
            String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
    intent.putExtra("data", imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);



}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {


            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            Log.e("URI", imageUri.toString());
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);




        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

That imageUri you pass to the Intent-  the image file is saved there.  Just save the URI in SharedPreferences or other persistant storage and check that storage next time you launch your app.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working on me :

```
private void takePicture() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    try {
        mImageCaptureUri = null;
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(mFileTemp);

        }
        else {

            mImageCaptureUri = InternalStorageContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;

        }
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.d("error", "cannot take picture", e);
    }
}
```

> This is how to define mFileTemp

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
File mFileTemp;
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
//this is like that 
//any folder name/you can add inner folders like that/your photo    name122412414124.jpg
mFileTemp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"any folder name"+File.separator+"you can add inner folders like that"
        , "your photo name"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
mFileTemp.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
else {
mFileTemp = new File(getFilesDir()+"any folder name"+
        File.separator+"myphotos")+File.separator+"profilephotos", "your photo name"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
mFileTemp.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
```

> Your global variables

```
private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
private File mFileTemp;
```

**1) Define your global variables**

**2) Then define mFileTemp**

**3)Then trigger `takePicture()` method**

Comment: where is InternalStorageContentProvider.java please share

Comment: @Attaullah this answer a bit old, please follow this guide : https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html