# Android how to create a folder in internal memory?

Tags: android

This was the code i was using but it didn't work as i couldn't find any folder created.

```
File myDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "123");
myDir.mkdir();
```

The next code also wasn't working.

```
File mydir = context.getDir("users", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
if(!mydir.exists) 
{
    mydir.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: add folder in your assets folder in your android application oroject

Comment: @soemthing it won't create a folder dynamically with code

Comment: @OP what did you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: I answered this question on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562696/how-can-i-save-an-image-to-my-app/35562884#35562884)

Answer (score 0):

You won't see it on your SD-Card as long as you are using MODE_PRIVATE. Only your application can access that folder. You probably can try Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().

Comment: i am trying to make one in internal storage as kitkat and above applications are not allowed to Read and Write External Memory

Comment: In that case you are doing it right. Does getFilesDir().list() return the folder you made? (After calling mkdirs() obviously)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile"); //Getting a file within the dir.
```

Answer (score 0):

> i couldn't find any folder created

You and users cannot access [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), except via some command-line tools, or by using an emulator, or by using a rooted device.

> The next code also wasn't working

That is also internal storage.

If you are expecting to see something when you plug your device into your desktop OS, that is [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) from the standpoint of the Android SDK. You also have to use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to get any files created on external storage to show up when you browse through your desktop OS file manager.

Comment: I am just creating a folder where i want to save  some data related to the appliccation .Suggest me some way.

Comment: @AbhiWill12: Your first snippet of code is fine. You just cannot browse to that location.